# Rebinding keyboard

Tags: ubuntu, keyboard

When using vim or emacs a lot the control key is used far more often than the caps lock key and it seems sensible from an ergonomic point of view to have the control key in the place that the caps lock key is.

Is there are a system-wide way to rebind the caps lock key to be the control key in Ubuntu?

Preferably I'd like something that is going to be more or less a permanent change.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`System | Preferences | Keyboard | Layouts | Layout Options... | Ctrl key position | Make CapsLock an additional Ctrl`

Answer (score 0):

call xmodmap somewhere in Xsessions/xinitrc's; may be rewritten at package updates.